# delete item from a dojo.store.jsonrest

Tags: rest, dojo, store

I started with this tutorial http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/store_driven_tree/

after setting up my ServerSide Restfull Service everything is working so far. I made a contextmenu for the tree by:

```
<ul dojoType="dijit.Menu" id="contextMenu" style="display: none;">
<li dojoType="dijit.MenuItem" iconClass="dijitEditorIcon dijitEditorIconDelete" onclick="pages.remove(tn.item.id);">delete page</li>
</ul>

<script type="dojo/connect">
var menu = dijit.byId("contextMenu");
menu.bindDomNode(this.domNode);

dojo.connect(menu, "_openMyself", this, function(e){
    // get a hold of, and log out, the tree node that was the source of this open event
    tn = dijit.getEnclosingWidget(e.target);

    // contrived condition: disable all menu items except the "New Page" item
    dojo.forEach(menu.getChildren(), function(child){
        if(child.label != "Neue Seite")
        {
            child.set('disabled', typeof tn.item == 'undefined');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Now I know on wich node the user made the right click for the contextmenu and delete it with "pages.remove(tn.item.id);" from the Database. To notify the tree I´m overriding the remove function:

```
remove: function(objectId){

    this.onDelete({id: objectId});
    return dojo.store.JsonRest.prototype.remove.apply(this, arguments);

}
```

Everything works as expected but if im now doing some other things with the items in the tree like drag n drop an item to the root i was deleting a child before. The tree isn't showing it correctly anymore. I think the remove method of the store only sends the DELETE query to the Server but don't removes the item from the store. How can i get the array of the items in store to check and maybe to delete items?

Answer (score 0):

The dijit.Tree is a presentation of an underlying dojo.data model, and any changes that you want to make to the tree really need to be done to the underlying data store.  See the description here: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/Tree.html#dijit-tree  So, instead of overriding the remove function, you should instead use the dojo.data API to modify the store, and then rerender the tree to reflect the changes.  The best source for looking at the various methods available is in the dojo nightly files.  Specifically, the dojo.data files are here: http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojo/data/

```
var item = tree.fetchItemByIdentity("selectedItem");  //find the item you want to remove
store.deleteItem(item);               //delete the item from the data store
store.save();                         //save the change made to the store
```

Comment: Would you consider explaining your code, so that anyone who reads can know why it would work?

Comment: I'm not using a dojo.data model. As you may have seen in the Tutorial, the store is directly connected with the tree. Anyway I figured out that the delete is working well. The problem only occurs if the old parent don't have a child after deleting. If I now add a new child or drag an other child to the Parent a plus sign is appearing but without funcionality. Any Ideas?

Comment: For some reason the reference to the new/addnl child is not being set properly.  The plus sign means that the tree recognizes the child, but something is not right with the underlying pointers... My understanding of the tree is that it uses the dojo.data model underneath, regardless of whether your data is in a dojo.data model or a dojo.store.  It may be significant, as discussed here: http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/creating_stores/  that "that a store does not dictate the actual data structure of a set of objects."  So it may be an issue of the store talking w/ the tree.

Comment: I would also look here: http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2011/02/15/dojo-object-stores/   specifically under the part about "Working with Existing Widgets and Stores".  It talks abt how most of the existing widjets still work w/ the old dojo.data model, and discusses object hierarchy issues btwn parents and children...