# How To reset the OnDemandGrid

Tags: dojo, dgrid

I am using OnDemandGrid with JSONrest store in my application.For the first time,the grid is loading fine , if i search again for other data,the data already in the Grid is getting overlapped with new data.Can someone tell me how to reset or refresh the OnDemandGrid?

Here is my code,

```
           function (request, Memory, OnDemandGrid,JsonRest) {

            var jsonstore = new JsonRest({target: url,idProperty: "srno"});
            grid = new OnDemandGrid({
                store: jsonstore,
                columns: Layout,
                minRowsPerPage : 40,
                maxRowsPerPage : 40,
                keepScrollPosition : true,
                loadingMessage: "Loading data...",
                noDataMessage: "No results found."
            }, "grid");
            grid.startup();
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Here's an Example taken from http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/39150-dojox.grid.DataGrid-how-to-clear-results

```
var newStore = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({data: {  identifier: "",  items: []}});
var grid = dijit.byId("grid");
grid.setStore(newStore);
```

}

to clear the Results of a Grid.

We use an similar case to delete our used ItemFileReadStore:

```
var emptyStore = clearStore();
dijit.byId("selectGemarkung").store = emptyStore;
```

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE 1:**
Look at this : [delete item from a dojo.store.jsonrest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8942683/delete-item-from-a-dojo-store-jsonrest)

I think jsonstore.remove() will do it.

Regards, Miriam

Comment: Using jsonreststore ,how to achieve this?

Comment: Updated my Answer - maybe this is the way

Answer (score 0):

Collection data should be set to null; else refresh() wont work. Also collection data should not be assigned blank store object `dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore`.

```
grid.collection.setData("");
grid.refresh();
```

Since we are removing collection from OnDemandGrid internal dstore errors will be logged in console for below js files.

```
dstore/Trackable.js,
dstore/Memory.js,
dstore/Promised.js
```