# dgrid (onDemandGrid) loads on first time button click, but error on second time button is clicked

Tags: dojo, dgrid

Thanks to some previous help here, I got the Dojo dgrid to work; and even figured out how to tie it to data from my rest service.

Now I added an input box, a button, and all the logic happens on the button-click.  But the second time I click the button, even with the same input value in the input field, I get an error.

ERROR:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'element' of undefined   in StoreMixin.js:33

Including the picture so you can see my console.logs 
[image]

I read this [How To reset the OnDemandGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922363/how-to-reset-the-ondemandgrid), but is it necessary to check to see if grid exists and do different logic? Can't I just "new up" a new one each time?

CODE:

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props='title:"CustomersGrid"'>
    <label for="lastnameStartsWith">Lastname Starts With:</label>
    <input id="lastnameStartsWith" type="text" name="lastnameStartsWith" value="Wag" 
           data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox"
           data-dojo-props="trim:true, propercase:true" />
    <br />
    <br />  
        <button id="queryStudentsButton" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button"
        data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" 
        data-dojo-props="iconClass:'dijitIconTask'">
            <span>Query</span>
            <script type='dojo/on' data-dojo-event='click'>
    require([
        'dstore/RequestMemory',
        'dstore/Memory',
        'dgrid/OnDemandGrid'
    ], function (RequestMemory, Memory, OnDemandGrid) {
                    var url = '../students/' + dojo.byId('lastnameStartsWith').value; 
                    console.log("query students for dataGrid latsnameStartsWith:" + dojo.byId('lastnameStartsWith').value);             

                    require(['dojo/request'], function(request){
                        request.get(url,
                             {headers: {"Content-Type": 'application/json',
                                        "username": securityConfig.username,
                                        "password": securityConfig.password}}
                               )
                            .then(function(response){
                                //console.log("string response=" + response); 
                                var respJSON = JSON.parse(response);
                                var respDataForDGrid = respJSON.recordset;
                                console.log("got respJSON back, num rows= " + respDataForDGrid.length);     


                                //================================================          
                                // Create an instance of OnDemandGrid referencing the store
                                console.log("Debug1");             

                                var grid2 = new OnDemandGrid({
                                    collection: new Memory({ data: respDataForDGrid }),
                                    columns: {
                                        student_id: 'ID',
                                        student_firstname: 'First Name',
                                        student_lastname: 'Last Name',
                                        student_city: 'City',
                                        student_state: 'State',
                                        student_zip: 'Zip'
                                    }
                                }, 'grid2');                                    

                                console.log("Debug2");             

                                grid2.startup();
                                console.log("Debug3");             

                             },
                             function(error){
                                console.log("Error=" + error); 
                                //dom.byId('studentFeedback').value += response;
                             }); 
                    });
    });
            </script> 
        </button>
<h2>My demoGrid - From JSON RestService (Database)</h2>
<div id='grid2'></div>

</div>
```

**Part 2 -**

[image]

I tried mix of your code and code on this page: 
[How To reset the OnDemandGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922363/how-to-reset-the-ondemandgrid)

```
  if (grid2Registered){
    console.log("reuse existing grid"); 
    grid2Registered.set('collection', memStore);
    // refresh: clear the grid and re-queries the store for data. 
    grid2Registered.refresh();  
    }
    else{...
```

Doc here (https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/blob/v0.4.3/doc/components/core-components/OnDemandList-and-OnDemandGrid.md) says:

> Clears the grid and re-queries the store for data. If
>   keepScrollPosition is true on either the instance or the options
>   passed to refresh, an attempt will be made to preserve the current
>   scroll position. OnDemandList returns a promise from refresh, which
>   resolves when items in view finish rendering. The promise resolves
>   with the QueryResults that were rendered.

Comment: If you have the grid created already, it's always advisable (at least this is what I do) to refresh the grid with new store provided your structure/columns remains same. This way, you avoid the overhead of creating a grid every time there is a query.

Comment: So how would you implement that?  Keep a counter? Or check how to check if my grid2 is previously defined?

Comment: If you take templated approach i.e. defining widget in html, you can use data-dojo-attach-point to reference the grid. If you take programmatic approach, you can assign an id (Please note that id's must be unique for each dijit that you use) to the grid and refer it as dijit.byId('yourId').

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one has been tough! Below a working example.

First I switched from declarative to programmatic for the onClick function: declarative scripts are parsed by dojo, and as a consequence you cannot examine them (set break points, etc.) under the debugger (at least I don't know how to do that). So it seems to me good practice to avoid them.

Then, indeed the bug is due to re-instantiating the dgrid with the same id, so that you do need  a way to detect that the dgrid already exists. But there is a trick: for dgrids to be properly handled by the dijit system, they need to be mixed in with the dijitRegistry extension. See [here](https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/blob/master/doc/components/extensions/DijitRegistry.md) for details.

Then you can use registry.byId('grid2') to detect that the dgrid already exists.

Also I had to skip the respDataForDgrid part and used directly respJSON instead (may be due to a difference with your server side(?) - I used a simple text file with a json array on the server side).

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML><html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Neal Walters stask overflow test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="dojo-release-1.12.2-src/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css"
    media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="dojo-release-1.12.2-src/dgrid/css/dgrid.css" media="screen">

</head>
<body class="claro">
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane"
        data-dojo-props='title:"CustomersGrid"'>
        <label for="lastnameStartsWith">Lastname Starts With:</label> <input
            id="lastnameStartsWith" type="text" name="lastnameStartsWith"
            value="Wag" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox"
            data-dojo-props="trim:true, propercase:true" /> <br /> <br />
        <button id="queryStudentsButton" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button"
            data-dojo-props="iconClass:'dijitIconTask', onClick: myClick">Query</button>
        <h2>My demoGrid - From JSON RestService (Database)</h2>
        <div id='grid2'></div>

    </div>
    <script src="dojo-release-1.12.2-src/dojo/dojo.js"
        data-dojo-config="async:true"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            require(["dojo", "dojo/parser", "dojo/domReady!"],
            function(dojo, parser){
                parser.parse();
            });
        function myClick(){
        var url = 'students/' + dojo.byId('lastnameStartsWith').value, securityConfig = {username: 'john', password: 'Doe'}; 
                    console.log("query students for dataGrid latsnameStartsWith:" + dojo.byId('lastnameStartsWith').value);             

                    require(['dojo/_base/declare', 'dojo/request', "dijit/registry", "dstore/RequestMemory", "dstore/Memory", "dgrid/OnDemandGrid", "dgrid/extensions/DijitRegistry"], function(declare, request, registry, RequestMemory, Memory, OnDemandGrid, DijitRegistry){
                        request.get(url,{})
                            .then(function(response){
                                console.log("string response=" + response); 
                                var respJSON = JSON.parse(response);
                                //var respDataForDGrid = respJSON.recordset;
                                //console.log("got respJSON back, num rows= " + respDataForDGrid.length);     


                                //================================================          
                                // Create an instance of OnDemandGrid referencing the store
                                console.log("Debug1");             
                                var theGrid = registry.byId('grid2');
                                if (theGrid){
                                    theGrid.set('collection', new Memory({data: respJSON}));
                                }else{
                                    var grid2 = new (declare([OnDemandGrid, DijitRegistry]))({
                                        collection: new Memory({ data: respJSON }),
                                        columns: {
                                            student_id: 'ID',
                                            student_firstname: 'First Name',
                                            student_lastname: 'Last Name',
                                            student_city: 'City',
                                            student_state: 'State',
                                            student_zip: 'Zip'
                                        }
                                    }, 'grid2');                                    

                                    console.log("Debug2");             

                                    grid2.startup();
                                    console.log("Debug3"); 
                                }            

                             },
                             function(error){
                                console.log("Error=" + error); 
                                //dom.byId('studentFeedback').value += response;
                             }); 
                    });
        };
            </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I will continue to try to move to programmatic code; I have a mix of different samples that I started with.  This has been a great learning exercise, but I can see it will take much more time than I had planned.  I new to refactor my code, learn how to use more small pure functions.  I already started trying to work on the SELECT logic with some success (to find which row the user clicked on). Can you look at my "Part 2" above? Original error went away, but new rows seems to overwrite old rows (show both letters at once).

Comment: I only posted code fragments: Had this at the top:  <script type="text/javascript" src="../../dojo/dojo.js"
  data-dojo-config="parseOnLoad: false, async:true"></script> so don't think I needed your parser.parse.  
Also had this close to the top:  <script type="dojo/require">
  dom: "dojo/dom", registry: "dijit/registry"
 </script>  to get the dijit/registry in a slightly different way

Comment: You do need to keep parser.parse. See https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/declarative/ for the explanation. You can remove the "parseOnLoad: false;" part. For the <script type="dojo/require">... this is also part of the declarative way. I can only agree with your statement to go declarative and refactor toard small functions. I recommend you go one step beyond and go AMD modules. See https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/modules/. There is a learning curve, but it is rewarding.

Comment: I meant "to go programmatic" (not declarative) in my comment above. As per new rows overlapping older ones, it could be due to a javascript error (may be visible on your console ?), although I don't see anything wrong in the part 2 fragment you provided. Have you tried without the refresh ?

Comment: I didn't add the DijitRegistry on the "var grid2 - new ..." as you clearly mentioned.  Actually, I think I had "parseOnLoad: true", and when I include parser.parse again, it tells me that some menuitem in the container structure already exists.  On the way to getting this thing to work!